# Excluding System Databases while excecuting sp_databases in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am retrieving the database list by executing the **sp_databases** stored proc. Is there any way I can exclude system databases from this list? I **do not** want to use the query SELECT name FROM dbo.sysdatabases where dbid > 6.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp_databases takes no params.

The only thing you can do is use the INSERT EXEC pattern to insert into a table var and then select from the table var and exclude the dbs you want to exclude. Seems a bit messy, can you expand the context of this problem?

This works, but it is a little hacky:

```
create table #t (db_name varchar(255), db_size int, remarks text) 

insert #t 
exec sp_databases

select * from #t
where db_name not in ('master', 'model', 'tempdb', 'msdb')
```

Comment: This throws an exception with the following message: "EXECUTE cannot be used as a source when inserting into a table variable." pls help

Comment: I know these commands work with SqlServer 2005 and above. I'm using SqlServer 2008, but still I get this message

Comment: see the amended answer, changed it to a table var